# Dynamically Update Existing Data with Prisma

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, next.js, prisma

I encountered a problem using next.js in the api routes. Here is the code in question:

```
////////
schema
////////

model Movie {
  id Int @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  year Int
}

///////
fetch request
///////

async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      title: formData.title,
      year: formData.year
      
    });

    const response = await fetch('/api/movie/[id]', {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })

    return await response.json()
  }
```

```
//////
[id].js
//////

export default async({query: { id }, movies}, req, res) => {
    
    const data = JSON.parse(req.body)


    const updateMovie = await prisma.movie.update({
        where: {
            id: parseInt(id) 
        },

        data
        
    })

    res.json(updateMovie)
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {

    const movies = await prisma.movie.findMany()

    return {
        props: {
            data: movies
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this code will update the data with an ID of “1”. But what if I wanted to update data with the ID of “4”? How would I do this without having to manually go in the code and change the ID every time?

I have tried putting this variable where the ID is:

```
const movieId = movies.map((movie) => movie.id === id)
```

but I get this error every time:

'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'

I don't know what else to do? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the best approach here is to create a dynamic API route like `/api/movie/[id]` and then you send a `PUT` request e.g. `/api/movie/12345abcd`, afterwards you pass the `id` in the prisma update query

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still kept giving me the same error. What would I put after the "id" in the prisma update where query? I definitely think you pointed me in the right direction though so much appreciated!

Comment: since your `id` is int did you try to do `id: parseInt(id)` ?

Comment: yes, i tried that just now and it still didn't work. If I posted more code on here would that help?

Comment: yes, can you post the code for the fetch request, one thing though, you don't need to parse the body of `req` next.js middleware do that already.

Comment: What is the value of `data`? Invalid value of data also might cause this issue.

Comment: I updated the original post with more code including the fetch request. Thanks to everyone for the input.